# java.util.Date inconsistent increment in scala

Tags: java, scala, datetime

I am tried to print 30 consecutive dates. The following is my code

```
val myDate: Long = LocalDate.parse("2017-07-01").atStartOfDay()
  .toInstant(ZoneOffset.of("+0")).getEpochSecond * 1000
val sdf: SimpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")

(0 to 29).foreach(i => println(sdf.format(new Date(myDate + 24 * 3600 * 1000 * i))))
```

However output does not consecutive:

```
2017-07-01
2017-07-02
2017-07-03
2017-07-04
2017-07-05
2017-07-06
2017-07-07
2017-07-08
2017-07-09
2017-07-10
2017-07-11
2017-07-12
2017-07-13
2017-07-14
2017-07-15
2017-07-16
2017-07-17
2017-07-18
2017-07-19
2017-07-20
2017-07-21
2017-07-22
2017-07-23
2017-07-24
2017-07-25
2017-06-06 <--- !!!!!!
2017-06-07
2017-06-08
2017-06-09
2017-06-10
```

What is the reason of this behavior and how to fix it?

Comment: `int` math overflow: `24 * 3600 * 1000 * 25 = -2134967296`. You need to force `long` math.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your math must overflow somewhere (integer math). Coerce the terms to `long` before you begin multiplication (you can append `L`) like

```
(0 to 29).foreach(i => println(sdf.format(new Date(myDate + 24L * 3600 * 1000 * i))))
```

Or, use [`TimeUnit.DAYS`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html#DAYS) which can handle this correctly; something like

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit
```

and then

```
(0 to 29).foreach(i => println(sdf.format(new Date(myDate + TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(i)))))
```

But, since we're using `LocalDate` anyway; it's probably better to write it like

```
import java.time.{Instant, LocalDate, ZoneOffset}
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit

val dtf: DateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE
val ld: LocalDate = LocalDate.parse("2017-07-01")
(0 to 29).foreach(i => println(dtf.format(ld.plusDays(i))))
```

Comment: *"Prefer `TimeUnit.DAYS`"???* Wouldn't your preference be to stay way, waayyy clear of `SimpleDateFormat` if you have `LocalDate` support (see line 1 of question code)? Because even your code will produce incorrect result when it crosses Daylight Savings Time.

Comment: You're right about `int` math overflow: `24 * 3600 * 1000 * 25 = -2134967296`

Answer (score 1):

Such a simple task really doesn't need such complicated calculations.

```
import java.time.LocalDate
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit.DAYS

Seq.iterate(LocalDate.parse("2017-07-01"), 30)(DAYS.addTo(_, 1))
   .foreach(println)
```

Comment: Deserves a symbolic extension method! Maybe `+@` for plus days.